laravel storage saving tmp/php... and not saving i wanted folder
I'm trying to upload an image from my admin panel, but the file isn't uploading or saving in the database.
I'm using the latest version of Laravel for my project. For your reference, I’m providing the full code of my ProjectController.php below. I would really appreciate any advice or solutions you could offer to resolve this issue.
Thank you!
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $projects = Project::all();
        return view('projects.index', compact('projects'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('projects.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'content' => 'required|string',
            'thumbnail' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        $thumbnailPath = $request->file('thumbnail')->store('thumbnails', 'public');


        return redirect()->route('admin.projects.index')->with('success', 'Proje başarıyla oluşturuldu.');
    }

    public function edit(Project $project)
    {
        return view('projects.edit', compact('project'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Project $project)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'content' => 'required|string',
            'thumbnail' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        $thumbnailPath = $project->thumbnail; // Eski görsel yolunu koruyun
        if ($request->hasFile('thumbnail')) {
            if ($thumbnailPath) {
                Storage::disk('public')->delete($thumbnailPath); // Eski görseli sil
            }
            $thumbnailPath = $request->file('thumbnail')->store('thumbnails', 'public'); // Yeni görseli yükle
        }

        $project->update([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'content' => $request->content,
            'thumbnail' => $thumbnailPath,
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('admin.projects.index')->with('success', 'Proje başarıyla güncellendi.');
    }

    public function destroy(Project $project)
    {
        if ($project->thumbnail) {
            Storage::disk('public')->delete($project->thumbnail); // Eski görseli sil
        }

        $project->delete();

        return redirect()->route('admin.projects.index')->with('success', 'Proje başarıyla silindi.');
    }
}

blade:
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')
<!-- Edit Project -->
<div class="max-w-[85rem] px-4 py-10 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 lg:py-14 mx-auto"> 
  <div class="mx-auto max-w-8xl">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h2 class="text-xl text-gray-800 text-left font-bold sm:text-3xl dark:text-white">
        Proje Düzenle
      </h2>
    </div>

    <!-- Card -->
    <div class="mt-5 p-4 relative z-10 bg-white border rounded-xl sm:mt-10 md:p-10 dark:bg-neutral-900 dark:border-neutral-700">
      <form action="{{ route('admin.projects.update', $project->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        
        <div class="mb-4 sm:mb-8">
          <label for="title" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium dark:text-white">Proje Adı</label>
          <input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="{{ old('title', $project->title) }}" class="py-3 px-4 block w-full border-gray-200 rounded-lg text-sm focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-blue-500 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none dark:bg-neutral-900 dark:border-neutral-700 dark:text-neutral-400 dark:placeholder-neutral-500 dark:focus:ring-neutral-600" required>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-4 sm:mb-8">
          <label for="content" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium dark:text-white">İçerik</label>
          <textarea id="content" name="content" rows="5" class="py-3 px-4 block w-full border-gray-200 rounded-lg text-sm focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-blue-500 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none dark:bg-neutral-900 dark:border-neutral-700 dark:text-neutral-400 dark:placeholder-neutral-500 dark:focus:ring-neutral-600">{{ old('content', $project->content) }}</textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-4 sm:mb-8">
          <label for="thumbnail" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium dark:text-white">Thumbnail</label>
          <input type="file" id="thumbnail" name="thumbnail" class="py-3 px-4 block w-full border-gray-200 rounded-lg text-sm focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-blue-500 dark:bg-neutral-900 dark:border-neutral-700 dark:text-neutral-400 dark:placeholder-neutral-500 dark:focus:ring-neutral-600">
          @if ($project->thumbnail)
            <img src="{{ asset('images/' . $project->thumbnail) }}" alt="Thumbnail" class="mt-4 w-32 h-32 rounded-lg">
          @endif
        </div>

        <div class="mt-6 grid">
          <button type="submit" class="w-full py-3 px-4 inline-flex justify-center items-center gap-x-2 text-sm font-semibold rounded-lg border border-transparent bg-blue-600 text-white hover:bg-blue-700 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none">Güncelle</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- End Card -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Edit Project Form -->

<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.16.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script>

  CKEDITOR.replace('content', {
    filebrowserUploadUrl: "{{ route('admin.projects.upload', ['_token' => csrf_token() ]) }}",
    filebrowserUploadMethod: 'form'
  });
  
  CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
    // CKEditor instance'ını al
    var editor = ev.editor;

    // Beyaz metin ve koyu gri arka plan rengi için stil ekle
    editor.document.$.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
      <style>
        body {
          color: #ffffff !important; /* Metin rengini beyaz yapar */
          background-color: #262626 !important; /* Arka plan rengini koyu gri yapar */
        }
        .cke_editable {
          color: #ffffff !important; /* Editördeki metin rengini beyaz yapar */
          background-color: #262626 !important; /* Editördeki arka plan rengini koyu gri yapar */
        }
      </style>
    `);
  });
</script>
@endsection

Model:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'content',
        'thumbnail',
    ];
}

I tried storage:link but dosen't worked.

You are validating the form data but are not creating a new entry into the Project model.
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'content' => 'required|string',
        'thumbnail' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $thumbnailPath = $request->file('thumbnail')->store('thumbnails', 'public');

    // Create a new project
    Project::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'content' => $request->content,
        'thumbnail' => $thumbnailPath,
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('admin.projects.index')->with('success', 'Proje başarıyla oluşturuldu.');
}

